# iOS file upload via "Take Photo or Video" contains no EXIF data

Tags: php, ios, iphone, image, file

I'm using:

```
$exif = exif_read_data($target);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
```

and just dumping out the EXIF, via:

```
die(var_dump($exif));
```

Now, when I upload via "Photo Library" using a picture I've just taken, I get the relevant rotation EXIF to be able to correct the orientation, but then I use "Take Photo or Video", it contains no EXIF, and then uploads landscape, the wrong orientation. It just returns the following:

```
array(7) { ["FileName"]=> string(12) "image-55.jpg" ["FileDateTime"]=> int(1467985594) ["FileSize"]=> int(1538119) ["FileType"]=> int(2) ["MimeType"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["SectionsFound"]=> string(0) "" ["COMPUTED"]=> array(4) { ["html"]=> string(26) "width="4032" height="3024"" ["Height"]=> int(3024) ["Width"]=> int(4032) ["IsColor"]=> int(1) } }
```

I really can't figure out why this is, is this intentional, is this a bug or do I need to change my code? Any advice is super appreciated.

Comment: How do you upload files?

Comment: Just via `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: You got any warnings, like `Illegal IFD size ...` ?

Comment: Does the taken photo (the one on your phone) have exif data? If not, then the case is clear... :)

Comment: No warnings or errors... using PHP7. Well the photo isn't stored when using 'take photo' from the file picker, so I can't really tell if it's intended or not, very frustrating!

Comment: Pictures that are uploaded via "Take Photo or Video" don't have exif. Apple knows the reason for that :D I have tried, and I get warning `Illegal IFD size ...`; and full exif data when I upload photo from library.

Comment: So is there no way to fix the rotation when "Take Photo or Video" is used?